# How to save Note with audio and photo in Iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I searched Evernote API for this.but it is not working , Is there any way to save text note ,audio and photo in single file unit? like this app [love notes](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/i-love-you-short-text-photos/id431101198?mt=8#)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it there in the API: http://www.evernote.com/about/developer/api/evernote-api.htm#_Toc291595517

Create a note is done via NoteStore: http://www.evernote.com/about/developer/api/evernote-api.htm#_Toc291595514

Comment: I checked this link. But My App is crashing when I am giving user name and password

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'EDAMUserException', reason: 'unknown'

Comment: This exception raises after providing username and password

Comment: http://digitalpericope.net/?p=27  I used this link and code. I added thrift folder and Edam folder from evernote API